# Send email with AMP Form

Tags: forms, email, amp-html

I have a form on my amp website right now it is not functional, all i want to send emails from that form whenever any user fills that form admin of  the site will receive the email with all the filled information.

The solution i have in my mind is by creating a php file in my amp folder and implement all the email code there, then the action in AMP page form will goes to that php file.

Is this a good approach or AMP has alternate approach to do this.

please guide me on this